# Javascript issue with precedence

Tags: javascript

I have built this function to replace a group of characters in a string by a random value from another list within a function:

```
function replaceExpr(a) {
  var expToReplace = 0
  var newSent = a
  while (expToReplace == 0) {
    if (a.search("zx") == -1) {
      expToReplace = 1
    } else {
        var startPos = a.search("zx");
        startPos += 2;
        var endPos = a.search("xz");
        var b = a.substring(startPos, endPos);
        var fn = window[b];
        if (typeof fn === "function") var newWord = fn();
      final = newSent.replace("zx" + b + "xz", newWord);
      newSent = final
      a = a.replace("zx" + b + "xz", "")
    }
  }
  return final
}

function appearance() {
    var list = [
        "attractive",
        "fit",
    "handsome",
    "plain",
    "short",
    "tall",
    "skinny",
    "well-built",
    "unkempt",
    "unattractive"
    ]
    return list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
}

function personality() {
    var list = [
    "aggresive",
    "absent-minded",
    "cautious",
    "detached from the real world",
    "easygoing",
    "focused",
    "honest",
    "dishonest",
    "polite",
    "uncivilized"
    ]
    return list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
}
```

An example :

```
var a = replaceExpr("Theodor is a zxappearancexz man. He seems rather zxpersonalityxz.")
alert(a)
// Theodor is a unattractive man. He seems rather cautious.
```

Everything works perfectly with the function but I have an issue related to it. As you can see, there's one grammar mistake : it's written "a unattractive" where it should be "an unattractive".

There's a function I usually use to to fix the a\an issue which is :

```
var AvsAnSimple = (function (root) {
  //by Eamon Nerbonne (from http://home.nerbonne.org/A-vs-An), Apache 2.0 license
  // finds if a word needs a "a" or "an" before it
    var dict = "2h.#2.a;i;&1.N;*4.a;e;i;o;/9.a;e;h1.o.i;l1./;n1.o.o;r1.e.s1./;01.8;12.1a;01.0;12.8;9;2.31.7;4.5.6.7.8.9.8a;0a.0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;11; .22; .–.31; .42; .–.55; .,.h.k.m.62; .k.72; .–.82; .,.92; .–.8;<2.m1.d;o;=1.=1.E;@;A6;A1;A1.S;i1;r1;o.m1;a1;r1; .n1;d1;a1;l1;u1;c1.i1.a1.n;s1;t1;u1;r1;i1;a1;s.t1;h1;l1;e1;t1;e1.s;B2.h2.a1.i1;r1;a.á;o1.r1.d1. ;C3.a1.i1.s1.s.h4.a2.i1.s1;e.o1.i;l1.á;r1.o1.í;u2.i;r1.r1.a;o1.n1.g1.j;D7.a1.o1.q;i2.n1.a1.s;o1.t;u1.a1.l1.c;á1. ;ò;ù;ư;E7;U1;R.b1;o1;l1;i.m1;p1;e1;z.n1;a1;m.s1;p5.a1.c;e;h;o;r;u1.l1;o.w1;i.F11. ;,;.;/;0;1;2;3;4;5;6;71.0.8;9;Ae;B.C.D.F.I2.L.R.K.L.M.N.P.Q.R.S.T.B;C1;M.D;E2.C;I;F1;r.H;I3.A1;T.R1. ;U;J;L3.C;N;P;M;O1. ;P1;..R2.A1. ;S;S;T1;S.U2.,;.;X;Y1;V.c;f1.o.h;σ;G7.e1.r1.n1.e;h1.a3.e;i;o;i1.a1.n1.g;o2.f1. ;t1.t1. ;r1.i1.a;w1.a1.r1.r;ú;Hs. ;&;,;.2;A.I.1;2;3;5;7;B1;P.C;D;F;G;H1;I.I6;C.G.N.P.S1.D;T.K1.9;L;M1;..N;O2. ;V;P;R1;T.S1.F.T;V;e2.i1.r;r1.r1.n;o2.n6;d.e1.s;g.k.o2;l.r1;i1.f;v.u1.r;I3;I2;*.I.n1;d1;e1;p1;e1;n1;d2;e1;n1;c1;i.ê.s1;l1;a1;n1;d1;s.J1.i1.a1.o;Ly. ;,;.;1;2;3;4;8;A3. ;P;X;B;C;D;E2. ;D;F1;T.G;H1.D.I1.R;L;M;N;P;R;S1;m.T;U1. ;V1;C.W1.T;Z;^;a1.o1.i1.g;o1.c1.h1.a1;b.p;u1.s1.h1;o.ộ;M15. ;&;,;.1;A1;.1;S./;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;Ai;B.C.D.F.G.J.L.M.N.P.R.S.T.V.W.X.Y.Z.B1;S1;T.C;D;E3.P1;S.W;n;F;G;H;I4. ;5;6;T1;M.K;L;M;N;O1.U;P;Q;R;S;T1;R.U2. ;V;V;X;b1.u1.m;f;h;o2.D1.e.U1;..p1.3;s1.c;Ny. ;+;.1.E.4;7;8;:;A3.A1;F.I;S1.L;B;C;D;E3.A;H;S1. ;F1;U.G;H;I7.C.D1. ;K.L.N.O.S.K;L;M1;M.N2.R;T;P1.O1.V1./1.B;R2;J.T.S1;W.T1;L1.D.U1.S;V;W2.A;O1.H;X;Y3.C1.L;P;U;a1.s1.a1.n;t1.h;v;²;×;O5;N1;E.l1;v.n2;c1.e.e1.i;o1;p.u1;i.P1.h2.i1.a;o2.b2;i.o.i;Q1.i1.n1.g1.x;Rz. ;&;,;.1;J./;1;4;6;A3. ;.;F1;T.B1;R.C;D;E3. ;S1.P;U;F;G;H1.S;I2.A;C1. ;J;K;L1;P.M5;1.2.3.5.6.N;O2.H;T2;A.O.P;Q;R1;F.S4;,...?.T.T;U4;B.M.N.S.V;X;c;f1;M1...h2.A;B;ò;S11. ;&;,;.4.E;M;O;T1..3.B;D;M;1;3;4;5;6;8;9;A3. ;8;S2;E.I.B;C3.A1. ;R2.A.U.T;D;E6. ;5;C3;A.O.R.I1.F.O;U;F3;&.H.O1.S.G1;D.H3.2;3;L;I2. ;S1.O.K2.I.Y.L3;A2. ;.;I1. ;O.M3;A1. ;I.U1.R.N5.A.C3.A.B.C.E.F.O.O5. ;A1.I;E;S1;U.V;P7;A7;A.C.D.M.N.R.S.E1. ;I4;C.D.N.R.L1;O.O.U.Y.Q1. ;R;S1;W.T9.A1. ;C;D;F;I;L;M;S;V;U7.B.L.M.N.P.R.S.V;W1.R;X1.M;h1.i1.g1.a1.o;p1.i1.o1;n.t2.B;i1.c1.i;T4.a2.i2.g1.a.s1.c;v1.e1.s;e1.a1.m1.p;u1.i2.l;r;à;Um..1.N1..1.C;/1.1;11. .21.1;L1.T;M1.N;N4.C1.L;D2. .P.K;R1. .a;b2;a.i.d;g1.l;i1.g.l2;i.y.m;no. ;a1.n.b;c;d;e1;s.f;g;h;i2.d;n;j;k;l;m;n;o;p;q;r;s;t;u;v;w;p;r3;a.e.u1.k;s3. ;h;t1;r.t4.h;n;r;t;x;z;í;W2.P1.:4.A1.F;I2.B;N1.H.O1.V;R1.F1.C2.N.U.i1.k1.i1.E1.l1.i;X7;a.e.h.i.o.u.y.Y3.e1.t1.h;p;s;[5.A;E;I;a;e;_2._1.i;e;`3.a;e;i;a7; .m1;a1;r1. .n1;d2; .ě.p1;r1;t.r1;t1;í.u1;s1;s1;i1. .v1;u1;t.d3.a1.s1. ;e2.m1. ;r1. ;i2.c1.h1. ;e1.s1.e2.m;r;e8;c1;o1;n1;o1;m1;i1;a.e1;w.l1;i1;t1;e1;i.m1;p1;e1;z.n1;t1;e1;n1;d.s2;a1. .t4;a1; .e1; .i1;m1;a1;r.r1;u1.t.u1.p1. ;w.f3. ;M;y1.i;h9. ;,;.;C;a1.u1.t1;b.e2.i1.r1;a.r1.m1.a1.n;o4.m2.a1; .m;n8; .b.d.e3; .d.y.g.i.k.v.r1.s1. ;u1.r;r1. ;t1;t1;p1;:.i6;b1;n.e1;r.n2;f2;l1;u1;ê.o1;a.s1;t1;a1;l1;a.r1; .s1; .u.k1.u1. ;l3.c1.d;s1. ;v1.a;ma. ;,;R;b1.a.e1.i1.n;f;p;t1.a.u1.l1.t1.i1.c1.a1.m1.p1.i;×;n6. ;V;W;d1; .t;×;o8;c2;h1;o.u1;p.d1;d1;y.f1; .g1;g1;i.no. ;';,;/;a;b;c1.o;d;e2.i;r;f;g;i;l;m;n;o;r;s;t;u;w;y;z;–;r1;i1;g1;e.t1;r1.s;u1;i.r3. ;&;f;s9.,;?;R;f2.e.o.i1.c1.h;l1. ;p2.3;i1. ;r1.g;v3.a.e.i.t2.A;S;uc; ...b2.e;l;f.k2.a;i;m1;a1. .n3;a3; .n5.a;c;n;s;t;r1;y.e2; .i.i8.c2.o1.r1.p;u1.m;d1;i1.o;g1.n;l1.l;m1;o.n;s1.s;v1.o1;c.r5;a.e.i.l.o.s3. ;h;u1.r2;e.p3;a.e.i.t2.m;t;v.w1.a;xb. ;';,;.;8;b;k;l;m1;a.t;y1. ;y1.l;{1.a;|1.a;£1.8;À;Á;Ä;Å;Æ;É;Ò;Ó;Ö;Ü;à;á;æ;è;é1;t3.a;o;u;í;ö;ü1; .Ā;ā;ī;İ;Ō;ō;œ;Ω;α;ε;ω;ϵ;е;–2.e;i;ℓ;";
    function fill(node) {
        var kidCount = parseInt(dict, 36) || 0,
            offset = kidCount && kidCount.toString(36).length;
        node.article = dict[offset] == "." ? "a" : "an";
        dict = dict.substr(1 + offset);
        for (var i = 0; i < kidCount; i++) {
            var kid = node[dict[0]] = {}
            dict = dict.substr(1);
            fill(kid);
        }
    }
    fill(root);

    return {
        raw: root,
        //Usage example: AvsAnSimple.query("example")
        //example returns: "an"
        query: function (word) {
            var node = root, sI = 0, result, c;
            do {
                c = word[sI++];
            } while ('"‘’“”$\''.indexOf(c) >= 0);//also terminates on end-of-string "undefined".

            while (1) {
                result = node.article || result;
                node = node[c];
                if (!node) return result;
                c = word[sI++] || " ";
            }
        }
    };
})({})
```

Now, the problem is that I can't find a way to use this function in conjunction with the replaceExpr. The  following obviously wouldn't work because of order precedence :

```
var a = replaceExpr("Theodor is " + AvsAnSimple(zxappearancexz) + "man. He seems rather " + AvsAnSimple(zxpersonalityxz).")
```

I just recently started learning javascript so my knowledge is rather limited. Any ideas how I could overcome this?

Thank you!

Comment: When replacing, you need to check the characters *before* your replacement and detect if there is "a" or "an". If so, drop the article as well and use `AvsAnSimple` to generate a new one. Otherwise do a straight replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to optionally match the " a " or "an" before your word in the input string and store that matched portion in a variable using the String.match() function, then check if that " a " or " an " exists in your matched string, do the manipulations you need to do and store that manipulated string in a separate variable, then use String.replace() to find that previously matched string again, and replace it wit 
 your manipulated string.  The regular expression you could use for this is /(\san?\s)?(zx\w*zx)/gm
[See the regular expression here for more context](https://regex101.com/r/VLdcgH/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Joseph! With your help I managed to find something that works by using your regular expression. Here's my function :

```
function replaceExpr(a) {
  var nbExprToReplace = 1;
  while (nbExprToReplace == 1) {
    if (a.search("zx") == -1) {
      nbExprToReplace = 0;
    } else {
      var currentGroup = a.match(/(\san?\s)?(zx\w*xz)/);
      var exprToChange = currentGroup[2];
      exprToChange = exprToChange.slice(2,-2);
      var exprToChange = window[exprToChange];
      if (typeof exprToChange !== "function") {
        alert("the keyword is not a recognized function!");
        break;
      } else {
        exprToChange = exprToChange();
        var final = exprToChange
      };
      if (currentGroup[1] === undefined) {
      } else {
        var newArticle = AvsAnSimple.query(exprToChange);
        final = newArticle.concat(" " + final)
      };
      a = a.replace(currentGroup[0], " " + final);
    };
  };
  return a;
};
```